# How to make expandable and collapsable table view in xamarin ios project

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am searching for some help or idea how to make expandable and collapsible table view in xamarin ios . I searched but did not get anything important to proceed further . I am new to ios and xamarin so any help would be appreciated.
Attaching the image for the better understanding.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create expandable tableview in Xamarin.iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403031/create-expandable-tableview-in-xamarin-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[EightBot - expand and collapse a UITableView for Xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/TheEightBot/EightBot.AutoExpandAndCollapse)