# Create expandable tableview in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create an expandable table view using `Xamarin.iOS` with accordion type functionality.

For example there will be some rows initially and taping on any row the cell will expand to some other rows in the table view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I made a sample of an expandable tableview [here](https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/ExpandableTableView) using only `Xamarin.iOS`

It looks like this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting the follow error when i tried to run your project|

Native linking error: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries'|
error : Native linking error: framework not found Reveal

Comment: ah sorry I use an app call reveal to debug the view hierarchy. I have removed it and pushed my commit should work ok now.

Comment: @IainSmith,  i want to delete the sections on Swipe for the above sample. How to achieve it ?

Comment: I feel like this is a different question, but seeing as I was down voted. I would start by looking at this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_4_-_editing/

Comment: It works good for images. But when I try to load the cell which contains of HTML content in UITextView control, height of each cell is not properly added to tableview.

Comment: This question was for an expandable table view. Sounds like you might need to ask another question with your specific case with HTML content